# Introduce PostgreSLQ password automatically using psql and -F parameter in bash script

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, password, postgresql

I'm trying to develop a cli using bash scripting to retrieve reports from a `PostgreSQL` database.

I'm using psql command and -F parameter to create a CSV with the result.

So the command is something like that:

```
psql -h myhost -p 5432 -U myuser -d mydatabase -W -A -F"," -c "<MY QUERY>" > $(date +%Y%m%d%H%M)_report.csv
```

When I execute this command, always the password request is prompted even if I use PGPASSWORD variable to set up the password before executing that.

If I only try to connect, it runs but if I add the -W -A -F -c and send that to a specific file, it doesn't work.

Is there any other possibility to automatically introduce the database password?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR**: just remove `-W` from your psql options.

> "When I execute this command, always the password request is prompted
>   even if I use PGPASSWORD variable to set up"

"Always ask for the password" is what the `-W` option is for. In particular it happens before checking with the server if a password is needed, which depends on the rules configured in `pg_hba.conf`.

From psql manpage:

> -W, --password
>      Force psql to prompt for a password before connecting to a database.
>
> This option is never essential, since psql will automatically prompt for
>      a password if the server demands password authentication. However, psql
>      will waste a connection attempt finding out that the server wants a
>      password. In some cases it is worth typing -W to avoid the extra
>      connection attempt.